# Review history and my reviews are identical only on worldbuilding

Tags: support, reviews

When I browse the review history, only my reviews show up, despite the URL ending with `/review/close/history`, and not `/review/close/history?userId=16186`.

This is specific to worldbuilding, and other stack exchange sites show other people's reviews at the location `/review/close/history`. (This is not just the 'close' category, the other categories are affected as well.) The same is also true for worldbuilding meta.

Can other people reproduce this bug?

Answer (score 2):

After some research, and checking what other people get on other stack exchange sites, I think I have managed to track this one down myself.

Yes, it turns out this one is not a bug, just a feature, related to what level of privileges you have reached. (The list of privileges is [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)).

Viewing all reviews in `/review/<category>/history`, and not just your own requires the privilege "access to moderator tools", so `/review/<category>/history` and `/review/<category>/history?userID=<number>` is identical to me because I have enough reputation to view the review queues, but not to view reviews performed by others, on space exploration, which I compared with, I had this privilege. The reason I thought this was specific to worlduilding was that the person I asked to check this on other sites, because I do not have review privileges there, happened to have the "access to moderator tools" himself.

Comment: This sounds correct to me :)